# how to retrieve imageUrl and Text data from cloud firestore database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here I am  trying to retrieve (imageUrl and Fname) data from cloud firestore database to web. The data get retrieve from cloud firestore database and displaying inside the Google chrome console .But it is  not showing on the website.

pls see the image link:- https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNg1h9iBxsBAZ_jBCNxpCyUptFx6R7WBidmHz7f6h3UWuIEl7OpmTlNdjyxMvL3RQ?key=NEVzdlpWMjF2eUFjeTdjbWhkODc3T1BWdll1b2ZB

//defualt.js code:

```
    db.collection("student entry").get().then(function(Snapshot) {
      Snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

          var posts_div=document.getElementById('posts');
     posts.innerHTML="";
     var data=doc.data();
     console.log(data);
    for(let[key,value] of Object.entries(data)){
   posts_div.innerHTML="<div class='col-sm-4 mt-2 mb-1'>"+
   "<div class='card'>"+
   "<img src='"+value.image+"' style='height:250px;'>"+
   "<div class='card-body'><p class='card-text'>"+value.name+"</p>"+
   "<button class='btn btn-danger' id='"+key+"' onclick='delete_post(this.id)'>Delete</button>"+
   "</div></div></div>"+posts_div.innerHTML;
 }
      });
  });
```

//Html code

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>Blogs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>

     <div class="container mt-2">

         <div class="row mt-4" id="posts">

         </div>

     </div>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first...make sure you remove -app from below line -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "/*************/",
        authDomain: "/******/",
       databaseURL: "/******/",
       projectId: "/********/",
       storageBucket: "/********/",
      messagingSenderId: "/******/",
      appId: "/*************/",
      measurementId: "/******/"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }); 
</script>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="defualt.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: what is `snapshot`? It doesn't seem to have a `val` property at all.

Answer (score 2):

`val()` is used in realtime database, but you are using firestore therefore change it to the following:

```
   db.collection('student entry').get().then(function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  var posts_div=document.getElementById('posts');
  posts.innerHTML="";
  //..
 });
```

Iterate inside the collection and retrieve the data inside the documents using `doc.data()`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: with the following code i able to retrieve from cloud firestore database.But it show only in the console of google-chrome not in the website

Comment: In the document is the property called `image`?

Comment: Yes in my firestore database and code for retrieving  I have use #image

Comment: see the image link :- https://photos.app.goo.gl/SG4hhVQrLSwkKspx7

Comment: Inside the forEach assign the image to src

Comment: I am not getting u

Comment: forEach(function(doc) { // has a doc function

Comment: I have edited  the above defualt.js Code. What i have done till now. Pls have a look .